# Does LSD use correlate with high achievement?

Tags: recreational-drugs

There is the famous quote by Steve Jobs

> Taking LSD was a profound experience, one of the most important things
>   in my life. LSD shows you that there’s another side to the coin, and
>   you can’t remember it when it wears off, but you know it. It
>   reinforced my sense of what was important—creating great things
>   instead of making money, putting things back into the stream of
>   history and of human consciousness as much as I could.

It seems to have [worked out rather well for him](https://www.google.de/search?q=apple+success).

Then there is [Francis Crick, John C. Lilly, Kary Mullis, Ralph Abraham, Stephen Jay Gould](http://www.famousscientists.org/14-famous-scientists-inventors-who-experimented-with-drugs/) which says,

> Many famous scientists and inventors of all ages have admitted to taking psychedelic drugs. Some of them have even **claimed that recreational drugs enhance creativity, inventiveness and intelligence**, while others have gone one to advocate drug usage.

Obviously this is anecdotal cherry-picked evidence and full of the various biases; LSD-using underachievers are most likely go quite underreported in the media and "Hey I did it without LSD!" isn't the most popular way to start a Nobel acceptance speech.

Is there a positive correlation between trying LSD at least once and high achievement?

Comment: Studies suggest that [Intelligent People Are More Likely to Use Drugs](http://www.alternet.org/drugs/intelligent-people-are-more-likely-use-drugs-why) (though those studies don't mention LSD specifically).

Comment: See also [Does LSD provide a creativity boost?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6834/2703)

Comment: The military did also tests with bad results. For example the Mkultra soldier.